# Parse utf-8 CSV file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to parse a CSV file that contains utf8 characters in Node.js.

Here's my code :

```
fs.readFile(path + files[i], 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); }
    console.log(data);
    // do something
});
```

The problem is that for some reason, the utf8 characters don't display properly (� in place of the real character).

I tried replaceing 'utf8' by 'utf-8' or write the whole object:

```
{encoding: 'utf8'}
```

but neither of these methods worked.

Later in my program, I'm sending the data to the browser with socket.io but this doesn't change anything making me believe that the issue isn't the terminal / browser.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It may still be a terminal display issue. Have you tried setting charset in the content-type header [like this?](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: For debugging purposes, try writing the content back to disk with fs.writeFile and reading the result in your favorite text editor.

Comment: Setting charset didn't work but by writing the data to disk with writeFile I saw that the resulting file had the same issues.

Comment: Sounds like your input isn't actually UTF-8.

Comment: I agree with @robertklep. I struggled with the same issue for a while, and it turned out the file had a different encoding than I thought. So check the actual encoding of the file.

Comment: It was indeed a problem of the source being encoded in the wrong format, thanks !